# how to update ignite caches when data is available in persistent store and when csvs are available?

Tags: mysql, ignite

I am trying apache ignite data grid to query cached data using sql.

I could load data into ignite caches on startup from mysql and csv and am able to query using sql.

To deploy in production, in addition to loading cache on startup. I want to keep updating different caches once I have data is available in mysql and when csvs are are created for some caches.

I can not use read through as I will be using sql queries.

How it can be done in ignite ?

Answer (score 0):

Read through cannot be configured for SQL Queries. You can go through this discussion in Apache Ignite Users forum.

http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/quot-Read-through-quot-implementation-for-sql-query-td2735.html

If you elaborate a bit on your use case, I can suggest you an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you're updating database directly, the only way to achieve this is to manually reload data. You can have a trigger on DB that will somehow initiate the reload, or have a mechanism that will periodically check if there were any changes.

However, the preferable way to do this is to never update DB directly, but always use Ignite API for this with write-through. This way you will guarantee that cache and DB are always consistent.